# Multi-touch design and interaction pattern, do you have any link?

Tags: design-patterns, multi-touch, interaction

I develop a collaborative business application on a multi-touch device like Microsoft Surface. However to my mind every collaborative application on a multi-touch device was made to share photos, to draw, to play, or for one person at time.

So, I have no reference and I'm having a hard time to imagine how multiple users can work on the same user interface, or how they should interact with my application.

My question is : do you know some blogs/books/links/authors which talks about design and interaction pattern on collaborative multi-touch device ? (To me collaborative means "multiple users at time").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that there are too many sources for you to follow on collaborative multi-touch interface. For example, these two groups are doing research on the topic:

http://www.egr.unlv.edu/~pinelle/projects/index.html
http://hci.usask.ca/research/digitaltables.shtml

A favorite of mine is the following blog on multi-user multi-touch musical interface.
http://ssandler.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2):

you probably need to belong here www.nuigroup.com .Its the best-est community around that helps UI designers, Multitouch programmers and such.

Hope it helps,

Anirudh